# Cannot destroy a widget called in a class. Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm sure I'm missing something easy, but this has been eating me up. I'm trying to create "Answer fields" and destroy them based on a drop down. I can place my widget fine but when i try to call my destroy function it doesn't create an error or destroy anything.

When you hit "2" on the drop down, I get my two fields when. When I hit "1" field "B" should disappear.

Not sure what i'm doing wrong

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import winsound


testbuilder = Tk()
testbuilder.geometry('1000x400')
testbuilder.title('Input your questions and answers.')

class add_remove_answer_fields:
    def __init__(self, master, textbox_yheight, textbox_xwidth, letter_text):
        self.text_box = Text(master, height = textbox_yheight, width = textbox_xwidth)
        self.letter = Label(master, text = letter_text)

    def place_field(self, textbox_xpos,textbox_ypos,letter_xpos,letter_ypos):
        self.text_box.place(x=textbox_xpos, y=textbox_ypos)
        self.letter.place(x=letter_xpos, y=letter_ypos)

    def destroy_answer(self):
        self.text_box.destroy()
        self.letter.destroy()

def buildanswers(answer):
    aentry = add_remove_answer_fields(testbuilder, 2, 50, "A.")
    bentry = add_remove_answer_fields(testbuilder, 2, 50, "B.")


    if answer == "1":
        aentry.place_field(500, 31, 480, 40)
        bentry.destroy_answer()

    if answer == "2":
        aentry.place_field(500, 31, 480, 40)
        bentry.place_field(500, 72, 480, 81)
    # if answer == "3":
    # if answer == "4":
    # if answer == "5":
    # if answer == "6":
    # if answer == "7":

#picking amount of answers to show up
answer_amount = IntVar(testbuilder)
answer_amount_dropdown = OptionMenu(testbuilder, answer_amount, "1", "2", command = buildanswers)
answer_amount_dropdown.place (x = 20, y = 220)

# Question and answer fields
questionlabel = Label(testbuilder, text="Question")
questionlabel.place(x=1, y=1)
qentry = Text(testbuilder, height=10, width=50)
qentry.place(x=1, y=31)
answerlabel = Label(testbuilder, text="Answers")
answerlabel.place(x=500, y=1)

testbuilder.mainloop()
```

*update*

Ron Norris answered this well. Here is what i believe would be the proper way to do my above code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import winsound


testbuilder = Tk()
testbuilder.geometry('1000x400')
testbuilder.title('Input your questions and answers.')

class add_remove_answer_fields:
    def __init__(self, master, textbox_yheight, textbox_xwidth, letter_text):
        self.text_box = Text(master, height = textbox_yheight, width = textbox_xwidth)
        self.letter = Label(master, text = letter_text)

    def place_field(self, textbox_xpos,textbox_ypos,letter_xpos,letter_ypos):
        self.text_box.place(x=textbox_xpos, y=textbox_ypos)
        self.letter.place(x=letter_xpos, y=letter_ypos)

    def forget_answer(self):
        self.text_box.place_forget()
        self.letter.place_forget()

def buildanswers(answer):


    if answer == '1':
        aentry.place_field(500, 31, 480, 40)
        print(len(testbuilder.winfo_children()))
        bentry.forget_answer()

    if answer == "2":
        aentry.place_field(500, 31, 480, 40)
        bentry.place_field(500, 72, 480, 81)
        print(len(testbuilder.winfo_children()))
    # if answer == "3":
    # if answer == "4":
    # if answer == "5":
    # if answer == "6":
    # if answer == "7":


aentry = add_remove_answer_fields(testbuilder, 2, 50, "A.")
bentry = add_remove_answer_fields(testbuilder, 2, 50, "B.")
#picking amount of answers to show up
answer_amount = IntVar(testbuilder)
answer_amount_dropdown = OptionMenu(testbuilder, answer_amount, "1", "2", command = buildanswers)
answer_amount_dropdown.place (x = 20, y = 220)

# Question and answer fields
questionlabel = Label(testbuilder, text="Question")
questionlabel.place(x=1, y=1)
qentry = Text(testbuilder, height=10, width=50)
qentry.place(x=1, y=31)
answerlabel = Label(testbuilder, text="Answers")
answerlabel.place(x=500, y=1)

testbuilder.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please provide [mcve] specific to the question you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is you're stacking widgets on top of each other. So that you have 2 'B' widgets on top of each other. You delete the one you just created, but the other one (from selecting '2' in the drop down) still exists as well. You can observe this by placing this print statement in you answer 1 test:

```
if answer == '1':
    aentry.place_field(500, 31, 480, 40)
    print(len(testbuilder.winfo_children()))
    bentry.destroy_answer()
```

Each time "1" is selected, the number of widgets increases, but they're stacked on top of each other so you can't see them. You should probably create widgets when needed as opposed to creating a bunch and discarding after.

Comment: I believe you are absolutely correct. Ok so just so i understand a reasonable correction for my code. I moved the variable assignment for creating the widget to the main loop so the widgets are created once. Then instead of destroying the widgets in my destroy_field function, iIinstead did a place_forget. Which appears to simply hide the widget instead. Does this seem like the best practice here?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct approach. It is also more efficient with computer resources, and maximizes application performance.